# Asynchronus call inside recursive function

Tags: javascript, promise, jquery-deferred, chromium-embedded

I am building a native desktop application in javascript using [CEF](https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/), And I have API to access filesystem from CEF. I have a senario,
in which I need to get names of all files(there could be trees of directories) within a particular directory. I need to get result array, I am using jquery promises. What I don't understand is: when do I resolve the promise to get final result array?

```
/*read all directories under this and get path*/
    var result = [];
    function _processEntries(dirPath) {
        var dirEntry = new NativeFileSystem.DirectoryEntry(dirPath), deferred = new $.Deferred();

        /*async call*/
        dirEntry.createReader().readEntries(
            function (entries) {
                for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                    if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                        _processEntries(entries[i].fullPath).done(function () {
                            deferred.resolve(result);
                        });
                    } else {
                        result.push(entries[i].fullPath);
                    }
                }
            },
            function (error) {
                console.log("Failed while reading dir:", error);
            }
        );
        return deferred.promise();
    }
```

// Calling function

```
_processEntries("C:/Users/abc").done(function(result){
    console.log("FILES ARRAY:",result);
});
```

Please suggest any other technique if I am doing it wrong :)

Comment: Try not to use jQuery promises when you could easily use much better promise libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm i see few errors you resolve the entire promise when the first child returns, you must wait for all your child directory finish there respective promise, and your are resolve a global variable not internal, look this example with the changes:

```
function _processEntries(dirPath) {
    var result = [];
    var dirEntry = new NativeFileSystem.DirectoryEntry(dirPath), deferred = new $.Deferred();

    /*async call*/
    dirEntry.createReader().readEntries(
        function (entries) {
            var promises = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                    promises.push(_processEntries(entries[i].fullPath));
                } else {
                    result.push(entries[i].fullPath);
                }
            }

            if(promises.length === 0) {
              deferred.resolve(result);
            } else {
               $.when.apply($,promises).done(function() {
                result.concat(arguments);
                deferred.resolve(result);
              })
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            console.log("Failed while reading dir:", error);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when do I resolve the promise

Immediately when the asynchronous call has ended. You would have the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) otherwise. Avoiding that, you can work with promises everywhere, and use proper composition with them.

Also, you should not initialise your `result` variable outside of the `_processEntries` function - you'd get huge problems with calling the function multiple times.

```
function getDirectoryEntries(dirPath) {
    // a promise helper function
    var dirEntry = new NativeFileSystem.DirectoryEntry(dirPath),
        deferred = new $.Deferred();
    dirEntry.createReader().readEntries(deferred.resolve, deferred.reject);
    return deferred.promise();
}
function _processEntries(dirPath) {
    return getDirectoryEntries(dirPath).then(function (entries) {
        var promises = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
             if (entries[i].isDirectory) {
                  promises.push(_processEntries(entries[i].fullPath));
             } else {
                  promises.push($.when(entries[i].fullPath));
             }
        }
        return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
             return [].concat.apply([], arguments);
        });
    });
}
```

Call it like this:

```
_processEntries("C:/Users/abc").then(function(result){
    console.log("FILES ARRAY:",result);
}, function (error) {
    console.log("Failed while reading dir:", error);
});
```